# No reputation for editing questions?

Tags: support, reputation, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

I have edited a few posts today and the edits got accepted. But, I did not gain any reputation.

What could be the reason?

https://stackoverflow.com/users/976554/eeerahul?tab=activity

Comment: Interesting that the bulk of your reps come from edits rather than upvotes.

Comment: Yeah, thats true, I review and edit questions mainly.

Comment: Well, based on the reputation profile, you have 1315 rep: 24 from questions ((2*5)+2)*2, none for answers. I think you _did_ reach the 1000 rep cap from edits! (btw I've still 209 points I can't justify. Maybe the whole of my calcs are wrong)

Comment: Well, I've also asked some questions with up-votes, and also earned 100 points as bonus. Could not get a single up-vote on answers though :-(. Hence, I've decided to answer questions only when I know, what I am talking about. My question stands answered though! Thanks a lot!

Comment: From your editor stats: "eeerahul had 622 edit suggestions approved." You've already got all the rep you can via editing.

Comment: You can see how much reputation you got from suggested edits on the last line of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation) page.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Until you reach 2,000 reputation, your edits have to be approved or rejected. Only if they are approved you gain the +2 reputation.

There is also a cap on the reputation that can be earned this way. Once you've had 500 edits accepted - that's 1,000 points - you don't earn any more reputation.

Comment: Yeah, thats true, but I did not gain any reputation even though the edits were accepted.

Comment: @eeerahul: Maybe you [conveniently] got some downvotes that canceled the edits out?

Comment: Ha ha! I've checked; even that is not the case.

Comment: That's interesting. Just a bug then? I'd retag it as such.

Comment: My suggestion would be to remove this cap, so that there is always some incentive for editing posts.

Comment: I agree with @eeerahul

Comment: @DantheMan Me too. And a suggestion: if a user passed 500+ edits and he doesn't have enough 2,000 reputations, he would deserve the right to edit posts directly without waiting for reviewers. I really **hate** those reviewers that *keep rejecting* my edits from e.g. [fixing **i** to **I**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_(pronoun)). They say: *too minor changes* — ironic.

Comment: @LaiVung: this is a highly unlikely scenario that one would reach 1,000 by making 500 accepted edits, but wouldn't have at least another 1,000 in reputation from one's own questions/answers.

Comment: I am not sure I am following this, But I get +2 rep everytime my suggested edit is accepted upon peer review. And I am not a high rep person either..

Comment: So all those who got over 2k rep no longer get +2 from edits because they can edit themselves? Ah so that's why. I am over 2k now so it is now much harder to get reps for us over 2k. Not getting +2 from edit anymore is a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 38):

You have the Copy Editor badge(500 edits) and therefore (`500 x 2 =  1000`) hit the 1,000 points cap mentioned by Purmou.